# Fast way to calculate the average all the c grouped by (a, b) tuples from zip(a, b, c)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have `ddd` as `zip()` of three arrays;

```
aaa = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2])
bbb = np.array([10, 10, 2, 2, 3, 2])
ccc = np.array([5, 15, 9, 11, 20, 10])
ddd = zip(aaa, bbb, ccc)
```

I would like to get average of elements in `ccc` grouped by the elements from `aaa` and `bbb` at the same index. In the example above, there are two `ccc` values where their corresponding `(aaa, bbb)` pair is `(1, 10)`, so I want the average of the two `ccc` values, 5 and 15.

So far, I only managed to calculate the average for `ccc` grouped on the value of `bbb` being the same:

```
>>> [(chosenb, np.mean([cc for aa,bb,cc in ddd if bb==chosenb])) for chosenb in set([b for a,b,c in ddd])]
[(10, 10.0), (3, 20.0), (2, 10.0)]
```

The expected answer is

```
[(1, 10, 10.0), (1, 2, 10.0), (3, 3, 20.0), (2, 2, 10.0)]
```

I also feel my one-liner way is too long and hard to read. How is the fast and simpler to read way for adding another layer to compare here?

Comment: Are all elements in `ddd` of the same length?

Comment: @Divakar Do you mean `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc` have the same length? Yes

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: @Divakar yeah, it should come first. I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Your problem description is confusing. You appear to want to **group** `(aaa, bbb)` pairs, and average each group. That's not the same as getting the average of `ccc` values for which `aaa == bbb` at that index is true.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes I didn't mean if a == b, but a group of (a, b) is the equal to another (a, b). I'm sorry for my English, I will edit the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you switch to using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this task, as it makes it far simpler to reason about data in *rows*:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'aaa': aaa, 'bbb': bbb, 'ccc': ccc})
>>> df.groupby(['aaa', 'bbb'], as_index=False).mean()
   aaa  bbb  ccc
0    1    2   10
1    1   10   10
2    2    2   10
3    3    3   20
```

Note how simple it was to produce a new dataframe with rows grouped by `(aaa, bbb)` tuples, then asking for the mean of the remaining columns.

If Pandas is not an option for you, there are also add-on projects that give `numpy` multi-dimensional arrays group-by capabilities, such as [`numpy-indexed`](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) and [`numpy-groupies`](https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies).

If you wanted to have a Python solution, you'd have to use a dictionary to group your values by first:

```
grouped = {}
for a, b, c in zip(aaa, bbb, ccc):
    grouped.setdefault((a, b), []).append(c)

result = [(a, b, np.mean(cs)) for (a, b), cs in grouped.items()]
```

Comment: But if I have many pairs of `aaa == bbb`, this way is not going to work?

Comment: @Jan: Why wouldn't it? Not that 'many pairs' is a clear enough problem description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Pandas works, thank you so much. But it seems python 2.7 does not have `statistics`. Anything can replace it?

Comment: @Jan: ah, my mistake, `statistics` is new in Python 3. I'll update.

Comment: For `result`, just note that I use `np.mean(cs)` and it works too.

Comment: @Jan: fair enough, these are numpy arrays as input, so we can assume it is available. I was going for a pure-python approach there.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1 :** Here's a NumPy way -

```
from __future__ import division # make sure divisions result in float

# Get unique scalar mappings for each group from aaa and bbb
idx = aaa*(bbb.max()-bbb.min()+1) + bbb

# For each group, get start indices, unique tags and counts
st,tags,c = np.unique(idx, return_index=1, return_counts=1, return_inverse=1)[1:]

# Finally use bincount to get grouped summations and then divide by the counts
# for grouped mean values. Zip for desired output format.
out = zip(aaa[st], bbb[st], np.bincount(tags, ccc)/c)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [189]: aaa = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2])
     ...: bbb = np.array([10, 10, 2, 2, 3, 2])
     ...: ccc = np.array([5, 15, 9, 11, 20, 10])
     ...: 

In [191]: out
Out[191]: [(1, 2, 10.0), (1, 10, 10.0), (2, 2, 10.0), (3, 3, 20.0)]
```

**Approach #2 :** Here's another that avoids `np.unique` and uses `array-slicing` and as such could be faster -

```
idx = np.lexsort([aaa,bbb])
a0 = aaa[idx]
b0 = bbb[idx]
c0 = ccc[idx]

m = np.concatenate(([True], (a0[1:] != a0[:-1]) | (b0[1:] != b0[:-1]) ))
tags = m.cumsum()-1
out = zip(a0[m], b0[m], np.bincount(tags, c0)/np.bincount(tags) )
```